# Image Correspondence - Matching regions of images

Tags: computer-vision

I have 2 images with the same content but might have different scale or rotation. The problem is, I have to find the regions of these images and match them with one another. For example, if I have a circle on image1, i have to find the corresponding circle in image2.

I just like to ask what the proper way of solving this is. I am looking at the matchShapes of opencv. I believe this problem is image correspondence but I really have no idea how to solve it!

Thanks in advance!

I have the following images:
Template Image => https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-q5qeExXUlpc/T7SbL9yWmCI/AAAAAAAAByg/gV_vM1kyLnU/w348-h260-n-k/1.labeled.jpg

Sample Image => https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-x0IWxV7JdbI/T7SbNjG5czI/AAAAAAAAByw/WSu-y5O7ee4/w348-h260-n-k/2.labeled.jpg

Note that the numbers on the images correspond to the proper matching of regions. These are not present when comaparing the images.

Answer (score 1):

As usually with computer vision problems, you can never provide too much information and make too many assumptions about the data you intend to analyze. Solving the general problem is close to impossible as we can't do human level pattern recognition with computers. How does your problem set look like? A few examples would be very helpful in trying to provide good answers.

You mention that the images have the same content, but with different colors. If that means it's the same scene photographed under different lighting conditions and from possibly different angles, you might need to do a [rigid image registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) first, so the feature points in the two images should overlap. If the shapes on your images might have multiple distortions compared to each other, you might be interested in non-rigid image registration.

If you already know the objects you are looking for, you can simply do a search for these objects in both images, for example with `chamfer matching` or any other matching algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Use ORB feature detector from OpenCV. Once you have the descriptors use BFMatcher with norm type NORM_HAMMING.